# Contenteditible span when I copy paste it turns text into spans

Tags: html, css, sveltekit

I have a span that acts like a textbox, but when I copy paste the text turns into spans.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2D6k.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6TXn.png)

I was expecting plain text. no spans

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Thanks, it's very difficult to debug code we can't see!

Comment: @AHaworth clcik omn link

Comment: Sorry, I think you have misunderstood. We require the code to be in the question, not as an image, and if at all possible as a runnable snippet. Yes, I can see code in your image, but it's not something people are going to type in for themselves to try things out.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably just how `contenteditable` works, it pastes HTML elements by default and creates new ones upon various interactions.

Some browsers support [`contenteditable="plaintext-only"`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_global_attributes_contenteditable_plaintext-only). In general, making content "behave" is a large undertaking. If `plaintext-only` is not an option and you need a flexible editor with formatting and the like, I would recommend seeking out a capable library instead.

Other than that you probably will have to handle the `paste` event and prevent its default behavior to do something else, like read plaintext from the [clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/clipboard) data and insert that instead.